# Django internationalization not working only on javascript static files

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, static-files, django-i18n

Background info: django 1.6.2, python 2.7.5

I recently started applying internationalization to my django project. I've managed to make it work in the models, views, and templates of an app (called metrics). However, when I try to apply internationalization on the static js files, `gettext()` does not seem to work since it always returns the string that I pass to it, ignoring the browser language. On the other hand, the `{% trans ... %}` tags in the html template (which uses those js static files) get translated correctly. This indicates that the issue resides in the internationalization of my js static files. Could anybody offer any guidance or suggestions?

This is a summary of my project configuration:

In the project settings I included:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)
LANGUAGES = (
  ('es', _('Spanish')),
  ('en', _('English')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'metrics/'),
)
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

The *djangojs.po* and *.mo* files concerning the js static files are located in the locale folder sitting in my root directory while the *django.po* and *.mo* files sit in the `locale/es/LC_MESSAGES` folder within my app. I ran `django-admin.py makemessages -l es` and `django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l es` from the appropriate directory and `django-admin.py compilemessages` from both (even though that may be redundant...). **Note that the .po files have no FUZZY tags.**

In the project's url.py file I included:

```
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('metrics',),
}
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
...
)
```

Perhaps this part is wrong since my *djangojs.po* and *.mo* files are in the root directory, but I tried locating them in my app directory and it did not work either.

Finally, an example of `gettext` use in my static js file (using d3js):

```
svg.append("g").append("text")
  .attr({"x":0,"y":17})
  .style({"text-anchor":"middle","fill":"black"})
  .text(gettext('Schedule'));
```

Any suggestions? And sorry about the huge write-up but I am trying to provide as much info as possible.